# How to use sun.awt.geom.Curve?

Tags: java, package, implementation

I'v got a library, which uses `sun.awt.geom.Curve` class. I found no such class in standard `JRE`. How to use it? May be it is possible to replace this class with some public one?

Answer (score 0):

Classes in `sun.*` packages are part of the implementation of the runtime and should not be used directly because they may change from one release to the next without a warning. You can see the documentation and source code of `sun.awt.geom.Curve` from OpenJDK for example here: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/awt/geom/Curve.html

Whether it's possible to replace it with something else depends on what the code does with it.